# short cut key for crystal report PRINT option in vb.Net 2008

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report. I want a shortcut key that can automaticaly print this report.
How can I set such a short-cut key ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Create pop menu on your crystal report viewer by using **context menu strip control**

Comment: You cant need to do it in a button click. this one is readily  available and if you click on tis like a button , it goes straight to printer.